# How to properly extend an interface with immutable properties to offer mutability via another interface

Tags: c#, interfaces, immutability, mutable

The following code snippets are simplified to demonstrate the context!
The actual interfaces and classes are **POCO**s having additional properties. The types are part of library I am working on, the interfaces are public API, the classes internal API.

I have:

1. an interface *IValue*

   ```
   public interface IValue
   {
       Int32 Value { get; }
   }
   ```
2. 2 different *IConfigurableValue* interfaces (2 separate git branches) which extend `IValue`, see further on

   ```
   public interface IConfigurableValue : IValue
   {
       void CopyFrom(IValue source); // is always part of the interface
   }
   ```
3. an implementation *AutoGeneratedValue*

   ```
   internal class AutoGeneratedValue : IConfigurableValue
   {
       public Int32 Value { get; set; }

       public void CopyFrom(IValue source)
       {
           Value = source.Value;
       }
   }
   ```
4. code which *needs to access the getter only* (via `IValue`) and code which requires a `IConfigurableValue` (no compile-time known implementation)

   External users of the library can implement `IValue` and `IConfigurableValue` on their own. Part of my library code creates an instance of `AutoGeneratedValue`. If the user provides a custom `IConfigurableValue` implementation my `AutoGeneratedValue` is passed to it, the user decides if to ignore it or not. Another API part accepts an instance of `IValue` and does something. It only needs to read the instance properties. This part of the API can be invoked without ever requiring any `IConfigurableValue` instances.

**My goal** for the library is a) to offer methods requiring an `IValue` instance and b) methods to auto-generated `IValue` instances or populate user-provided `IConfigurableValue` instances which can be used for part a.

I currently have 2 branches with the following `IConfigurableValue` definitions:

- `IConfigurableValue` will extend a separate *IValueConfiguration* as well as `IValue`

  ```
  public interface IConfigurableValue : IValue, IValueConfiguration
  {
      void CopyFrom(IValue source);
  }

  public interface IValueConfiguration
  {
      Int32 Value { set; }
  }
  ```
- and a `IConfigurableValue` which defines the setter itself, no additional interface

  ```
  public interface IConfigurableValue : IValue
  {
      new Int32 Value { set; }

      void CopyFrom(IValue source);
  }
  ```

With both options I need to cast `IConfigurableValue` to `IValue` to access the getter in part b of my library.
With option *no. 1* I need to cast `IConfigurableValue` to `IValueConfiguration` to access the setter.

Option *no. 2* denies me the usage via a *setter-only* interface because any `IConfigurableValue` is an `IValue`,
with *no. 1* I could use the `IValueConfiguration` if I need it. -- This is no actual requirement of my API but I don't know the future demands for the API.

Is there another option to achieve my goal and which option should be preferred?

Comment: @ckerth Yes, but I have to give you props for making this a good question though. I hope it will be well received on programmers.

Comment: @SimonForsberg That's why I consider this a *best-practice* question. I have 2 solutions, both working but having some drawbacks. Maybe there is a better solution I don't know of yet. I don't want opinion like "I like that better", I want to know if one or the other option should be used (or preferred) for a reason. or to shorten  "best practice"

Comment: Refresh my memory. What happens if you make `IConfigurableValue : IValue { Int32 Value { get; set; } }` ? Does that compile?

Comment: @RubberDuck first off: [CS0108](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s8070fc.aspx) -- but yes it should compile. I don't want it it for a reason of explicit implementation for `get` via both interfaces.  Example: `public class Sample : IConfigurableValue
{
    Int32 IConfigurableValue.Value { get; set; }
    
    Int32 IValue.Value { get; }
}`

Comment: @ckerth it might not be pretty *inside* your implementation, but it's probably the cleanest solution for the client code. I'd argue it matters way more how it gets called than implemented. An "ugly" implementation gets contained. An ugly interface (API not the keyword `interface`) pollutes your code base.

Comment: @RubberDuck I see your point. On the other hand an API is a contract "how to use my library". If a client implementation is clean doesn't matter to me, he has to fulfill my contract (that's what matters imho). As a side note, implementing `IConfigurableValue` is simple: auto-property POCO, applies to your proposed interface same as my 2 solutions. I will  consider your proposed solution nonetheless, thanks.

Comment: You're confusing children and clients @ckerth.

Comment: Is there a reason that `IConfigurableValue` needs to extend `IValue`? You could just have them as two different interfaces implemented by the same class

Comment: @BenAaronson Uhmm, that's the gist of the question. I **have** `IValue` and I want to extend it and how is this achieved properly. Because this question was formerly posted on *codereview* I have included actual code snippets.

Comment: @ckerth Right, I'm just wondering if maybe your needs would be served as well/better by having two separate interfaces where one does not extend the other. (i.e. `IValue` has `Value {get;}`, `IConfgurableValue` has `Value {get; set;}`, and you write `AutoGeneratedValue : IValue, IConfigurableValue`)

Comment: @BenAaronson With this approach part B of my library doesn't require the `IValue` to populate an existing `IConfigurableValue`. And the auto-generated field could be returned as `IValue`. So yes, for my API it can be done that way as an alternative. Side note: like RubberDuck' suggestion, different explicit implementations of `get` are possible. You may want to consider writing an answer for other users stumbling over this question. (because the gist of your answer is "don't extend it")

Answer (score 1):

Consider just doing this:

```
public interface IValue
{
    Int32 Value { get; }
}

public interface IConfigurableValue : IValue
{
    void SetValue(Int32 newValue);
}
```

The obvious disadvantage here is that callers of `IConfigurableValue` have to use an unusual, Java-like syntax for the setter instead of the normal C# syntax. Nevertheless, this solution is simple and easy to understand.

You should only define `CopyFrom` as an interface member if its implementation may vary between different implementing classes. If all implementing classes will use the same implementation of `CopyFrom`, just define it as an extension method instead:

```
public static class ConfigurableValueExtensions
{
    public static void CopyFrom(this IConfigurableValue destination, IValue source)
    {
        destination.SetValue(source.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach never exposes the property itself as mutable, simple but effective.